# nginx proxy_pass to webpack-dev-server gives 200 on index.html, but 404 for everything else in the same directory

Tags: nginx, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Probably the nginx people are going to be able to help more here.

I basically have a resource at `x.x.x.x:8081/bundle-login.js`.  I'm using `proxy_pass`.  I want to redirect `/Account/Login` to `x.x.x.x:8081/`.  I've also tried configuring `8081` to have its resources at `x.x.x.x:8081/Account/Login/bundle-login.js`.  Getting `200` accessing them both directly.

Getting 404s through the proxy for `bundle-login.js`.  The index comes up, no problem.  Suspicious that through the proxy `index.html` gives `200` but, for what should be in the exact same directory I get `404` for `bundle-config`.

```
location /Account/Login {
   proxy_pass   http://10.0.2.2:8081/;
   proxy_redirect off;

   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   location ~ \.css {
     add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
   }
}
```

Comment: Try `location /Account/Login/` (with a trailing `/`)

Comment: @RichardSmith I think that actually made it worse. I tried taking off the trailing / on the proxy, pass, too.  Doesn't help.